# Want to start my password with capital letter always?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am using Python 3.6 and working on Jupyter Notebook. My code for password validation using regular expression is working absolutely great. I just want to make an enhancement that my password should start with capital letter always. I don't know how to write the regular expression in my elif loop. The code is as follows:

```
import re
import getpass

pattern = re.compile(r"")

while True:
    my_str = getpass.getpass("Enter a password: ")

    if(8>len(my_str)):
        print("Password must be of 8 digits")

    if re.search(r"[a-z{1,9}]", my_str) is None:
        print("Your Password must contain 1 lowercase letter")

    if re.search(r"[!@$&{1,5}]", my_str) is None:
        print("Your Password must contain 1 special character")

    if re.search(r"[A-Z{1,5}]", my_str) is None:
        print("Your Password must contain 1 uppercase letter")

    if re.search(r"\d{1,5}", my_str) is None:
        print("Your Password must contain 1 digit")
    elif re.match(r"[A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]{8,}",my_str):
        pattern = re.compile(r"[A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]{8,}")
        password = pattern.match(my_str)
        print(password)
        break
else:
    print("Not a valid Password")
```

Comment: Your conditions do not seem to make sense, what are the exact requirement for the password?

Comment: I want to start my password with capital letter always

Comment: rest is working fine

Comment: I am sorry, but the rest is not working

Comment: Thank You Sir...I was giving condition that, password must contain atleast 1 digit, atleast 1 Alphabet both small and capital and atleast 1 special character..with not more than 8 characters..With these conditions, it's working fine..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this condition to test if the first character is an uppercase letter:

```
my_str[0].isupper()
```

Although, there is more that is wrong with your code

## Improvements

The conditions you describe in your `print` statements do not seem to match what you are testing.

By example the condition `re.search(r"[a-z{1,9}]", my_str)` will check if the password contains a lowercase letter or any of the characters `{`, `1`, `,` , `9`, `}`. You probably wanted to have the brackets outside the character set.

Furthermore your code flow is incorrect, by example your `else` clause of your `while` loop will never be reached.

A suggestion would be to use a `valid` flag that turns `False` whenever a condition is not met, the loop is finally exited only if the flag is still `True`. Otherwise the unmet conditions are printed and the loop starts again.

## Fixed code

```
import re
import getpass

while True:
    my_str = getpass.getpass("Enter a password: ")

    valid = True

    if 8 > len(my_str):
        valid = False
        print("Password must have at least 8 characters")

    if not re.search(r"[a-z]", my_str):
        valid = False
        print("Your Password must contain 1 lowercase letter")

    if not re.search(r"[!@$&]", my_str):
        valid = False
        print("Your Password must contain 1 special character")

    if not re.search(r"[A-Z]", my_str):
        valid = False
        print("Your Password must contain 1 uppercase letter")

    if not re.search(r"\d", my_str):
        valid = False
        print("Your Password must contain 1 digit")

    # This is the condition that checks the first character is a capital letter
    if my_str and not my_str[0].isupper():
        valid = False
        print('First character must be a capital letter')

    if valid:
        break
```